# How can I coerce a String into a &str for the purposes of implementing the ToSocketAddrs trait?

Tags: string, rust

When a string is stored as a `String` rather than a `&str` it fails to implement the trait `ToSocketAddrs`. The closest possible one that does is `impl<'a> ToSocketAddrs for (&'a str, u16)`.

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let url = "www.google.com".to_string(); // String
    let url2 = "www.google.com";            // &'static str
    let port = 80;

    // Does not work
    let tcp = TcpStream::connect((url, port));

    // Works
    let tcp2 = TcpStream::connect((url2, port));
}
```

This fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(std::string::String, {integer}): std::net::ToSocketAddrs` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:11
  |
9 | let tcp = TcpStream::connect((url, port));
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::net::ToSocketAddrs` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, {integer})`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <(std::net::Ipv6Addr, u16) as std::net::ToSocketAddrs>
            <(std::net::Ipv4Addr, u16) as std::net::ToSocketAddrs>
            <(&'a str, u16) as std::net::ToSocketAddrs>
            <(std::net::IpAddr, u16) as std::net::ToSocketAddrs>
  = note: required by `std::net::TcpStream::connect`
```

How can I coerce a `String` into a `&str` for the purposes of implementing the `ToSocketAddrs` trait? From the documentation for Rust 1.0, I thought that `String` would automatically move to `&str`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hauleth's answer will work for you, but it's not quite the whole story. In particular, your `String` isn't coercing to a `&str` because auto deref coercion does not kick in when trait matching, as per [RFC 0401](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md). Therefore, using a plain `&url` won't work in this case because auto deref won't be applied to it. Instead of getting an `&str`, you'll just get a `&String`, which doesn't have a matching impl for `ToSocketAddrs`. However, you can explicitly cause deref to happen with the dereference operator. In particular, `&*url` should work. (`&url[..]` also works because `[..]` is the syntax for "take a slice over everything", but it's a bit more verbose.)

Comment: Thanks to the link to the RFC. I'd been pulling my hair out wondering why functions would coerce and this wouldn't

Answer (score 5):

As `std::net::ToSocketAddrs` is implemented only on `(&str, _)` you need to take a slice of of the string using the `&url[..]` slice syntax:

```
let tcp = TcpStream::connect((&url[..], port));
```